# Adding an image through CSS rather than HTML 5

Tags: html, css

I would like to insert an image through my CSS style sheet rather than having a link in the HTML.

CSS code:

```
#bar {  
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background: #000 url(/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/bar.png) center no-repeat;
background-size: auto 200%;  
}
```

HTML5 code:

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Untitled Document</title>
         <link href="Untitled-3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
         <div id="bar">
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

The problem is that when I view this in my browser, I see nothing, just a blank page. 
Can you see any problem in my code, or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: The problem is in image's path. It contains a space.

Comment: Wrap the URL address by *quotes* `url("/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/bar.png")`

Comment: "I would like to insert an image through my CSS style sheet rather than having a link in the HTML." Any particular reason?

Comment: Are you loading the page locally or from a server?

Comment: @ZachSaucier It is, when there's white spaces in the path

Comment: Using a CSS validator would have caught the error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just create a folder for your test site, lets say `mysite`, then add an `images` folder and a `css` folder to it. Then add your images and css files to their respective folders.

Your folder structure would look like this:

```
/mysite
  /images
  /css
  index.html
```

Then you would link to your images like so:

```
background: url(../images/bar.png) center no-repeat;
```

This is generally how a website directory should be organized, so if your making a test site you might as well get in the habit of organizing it this way. And also avoid spaces in you folder and file names.

Comment: Thankyou very much, i will use this folder structure.

Comment: @bjbear123 No problem. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: I'd love to know why I got down voted. Any ways you don't need to use double quotes. I imagine the reason this fixed your problem is because you are linking to a file in a random location on your computer and not in the root directory.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help, its all greatly appreciated, and to be honest i don't know why anyone would of voted you down considering you was only helping and you solved my problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
background: #000 url(/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/bar.png) center no-repeat;
```

to

```
background: #000 url("/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/bar.png") center no-repeat;
```

And as an aside, in HTML5 you can omit the `type="text/css"` from your link tag.